# Python performance with replace that seldom replaces

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, replace

I'm writing a list of strings as tab delimited file, using python 3.6

It is rare, but hypothetically possible, that there are tabs in the data. If so, I need to replace them with spaces. Which I do like this :

```
row = [x.replace("\t", " ") for x in row]
```

The trouble is, this one line is responsible for about 1/4 of the runtime of the whole program, and it almost never is actually doing anything.

Is there a faster way to purge tabs from my data?

Is there any way to take advantage of the fact that it probably doesn't have any tabs anyway?

I've tried working in bytes instead of strings, and that made no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried various approaches and the fastest one is to perform a conditional replacement at indexes where a tab is present

```
def testReplace(sList):
    return [s.replace("\t"," ") for s in sList]

noTabs  = str.maketrans("\t"," ")
def testTrans(sList):
    return [s.translate(noTabs) for s in sList]

def joinSplit(sList):
    return "\n".join(sList).replace("\t"," ").split("\n")

def conditional(sList):
    result = sList.copy() # not needed if you intend to replace the list
    for i,s in enumerate(sList):
        if "\t" in s:
            result[i] = s.replace("\t"," ")
    return result
```

performance checks:

```
from timeit import timeit
count   = 100
strings = ["Hello World"*10]*1000  # ["Hello \t World"*10]*1000

t = timeit(lambda:testReplace(strings),number=count)
print("replace",t)   

t = timeit(lambda:testTrans(strings),number=count)
print("translate",t) 

t = timeit(lambda:joinSplit(strings),number=count)
print("joinSplit",t) 

t = timeit(lambda:conditional(strings),number=count)
print("conditional",t)
```

output:

```
# With tabs
replace     0.03365320100000002
translate   0.08165113099999993
joinSplit   0.027709890000000015
conditional 0.007067911000000038

# without tabs
replace     0.015160736000000008
translate   0.07439537500000004
joinSplit   0.017001820000000056
conditional 0.0065534649999999806
```

Comment: Thanks! On my machine, with my data, things were interesting. 
With strings, the join was slightly faster than the conditional. With bytes, the conditional was significantly slower than the original replace, and the join was about the same as join with strings (i.e. much faster than replace). I'll switch to the join for now, unless some even better answer pops up.

Comment: For me, this was even faster :

if "\t" in  "".join(row):
   row = "\n".join(row).replace("\t", " ").split("\n")

Answer (score 1):

Untested on a performance question, but I would use the csv module that knows about fields containing new lines or separators, and automatically quotes them:

```
import csv

with open(filename, 'w', newline='') ad fd:
    wr = csv.writer(fd, delimiter='\t')
    ...
        wr.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use csv, because I specifically do not want it to insert quotes.